# CSS proportionally background

Tags: html, css

i want to implement a proportional background image.

this code i have try but then the scrolling doesnt works and the other divs are in background and not visible?

```
.background {
background-image:url(xx);
background-position:50% 50%;
background-size:cover;
position:fixed;
left:0;
top:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
}
```

Have you maybe a better idea?

Thanks

Comment: make a complete HTML/CSS code that we can test

Answer (score 0):

If you try to fix the `div` behind the other elements you have to send it via `z-index`.

---

```
.background 
{ 
background-image:url(xx);
 background-position:50% 50%;
 background-size:cover;
 position:fixed; 
 left:0; 
 top:0; 
 right:0; 
 bottom:0; 
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 z-index:-1; 
}
```

---

The `z-index` will set the **z axis** less than the others. And you'll be able to set it like background.

Answer (score 0):

Add following to your background class

```
z-index: -1;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```